# str_replace function wont replace string if i use single quotes

Tags: php, str-replace

I using php's str_replace function to replace some text. Example below.

```
str_replace("{x+{\$v}}", "{x-{\$v}}", $this->introtext);

str_replace('{x+{\$v}}', '{x-{\$v}}', $this->introtext);
```

In first case it replace text, but in second case it is not doing so. What is difference between two?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [difference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) between `'` and `"`. Get rid of the `\` inside the single-quoted string.

EDIT: To clarify, a double-quoted string does some expansion (see the link), whereas the single-quoted one does not. `$` needs to be escaped with `\` inside double-quoted strings, but not in single-quoted strings. In the latter case, it would literally result in `\$`.

Answer (score 0):

The dollar sign and curly braces have special meanings when inside double-quoted strings. `$` is used to put content from a variable directly into a string. `{}` is used to wrap PHP variables in case their meaning is ambiguous.

For example `"$hello"` would put the contents of the variable `$hello` into the string, whereas `"{$hell}o"` would put the contents of the variable `$hell` into the string, followed by the literal letter o.

Single quotes don't have this at all (and are generally preferable when quoting more complex strings, for simplicity). So `'{$hell}o'` would be a string containing the actual characters `{$hell}o`.

It's a little unclear what exact strings you are trying to replace. To replace the literal `{x+$v}` with `{x-$v}` then use:

```
str_replace('{x+$v}', '{x-$v}', $this->introtext);
```